# Angular2 - passing ngFor item into a pipe as a parameter?

Tags: angular, parameters, pipe, ngfor

Im trying to pass an ngFor item into a pipe as a paramter but get an error:

> Exception: Call to Node module failed with error: Error: Template
>   parse errors: TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of
>   undefined ("{{name}} ng-container [ERROR ->]*ngFor="let rating of
>   ratings | groupFilter:{{name}} "

This is the html:

```
            <tr *ngFor="let name of measureNames">
            <td>{{name}}</td>
            <td><input class="form-control"></td>
            <ng-container *ngFor="let rating of ratings | groupFilter:{{name}} ">
                <ng-container *ngFor="let key of rating | keys">
                    <td *ngIf="key=='measureRating'"><input class="form-control" value={{rating[key]}}></td>
                </ng-container>
            </ng-container>
        </tr>
```

and this is my pipe:

```
    import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'groupFilter',
    pure: false
})

export class GroupFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(items: any[], args: string): any {
        console.log("Filter ARGS: " + args);
        return items.filter(item => item.measureName==args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `*ngFor="let rating of ratings | groupFilter:name"`. No `{{ }}` around `name`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove `{{}}` from `{{name}}`

`{{}}` **never** goes together with `(event)="..."` `[prop]="..."` or `*someDirective="..."`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151199/discussion-between-user-and-gunter-zochbauer).